# Failed to select data from PHPMyAdmin using PHP PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, phpmyadmin

This is my code:

```
<?php
//Connect to DB
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";

try {
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=users", $username, $password);
    // set the PDO error mode to exception
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
}
catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo "Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage();
}

function printResult($conn) {
    $sql = 'SELECT name FROM info';
    foreach ($conn->query($sql) as $row) {
        print $row['name'] . "\t";
    }
}
?>
```

But, when I run it, nothing gets printed. What's wrong?

Yes, my table is not empty. I am 100% able select & print data using MySQLi Object-oriented, but not working with PDO. What's wrong in my code?

Comment: you don't fetch anything after running the query

Comment: You dont look like you call the function. If you dont call a function it wont run

Comment: @Akintunde You can run the query like that, see the first example in the manual http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.query.php (actually looks like this is a modified version of that example in the manual). Most likely its because the function isn't being called, as Riggs stated.

Comment: Oh, Where should i call the function? I am newbie. Before foreach $sql = Select command?

Comment: Just do `printResult($conn)` after its been defined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To run a function you must call it.

```
<?php
//Connect to DB
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";

try {
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=users", $username, $password);
    // set the PDO error mode to exception
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
}
catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo "Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage();
    // and if this fails there is no point continuing so add an exit
    exit;
}

function printResult($conn) {
    $sql = 'SELECT name FROM info';
    foreach ($conn->query($sql) as $row) {
        print $row['name'] . "\t";
    }
}

printResult($conn);   // call the function

?>
```

Comment: Worked, thanks. Just one question: See this example: https://www.w3schools.com/php/showphpfile.asp?filename=demo_db_select_pdo

W3schools did not call the function "beginChildren" anywhere, how their code worked?

Comment: Thats a way more complicated example than the one you gave us

Comment: It all gets controlled by the Iterator Class in their code

Answer (score 1):

Call the function

```
<?php
//Connect to DB
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";

try {
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=users", $username, $password);
    // set the PDO error mode to exception
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
}
catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo "Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage();
}

function printResult($conn) {
    $sql = 'SELECT name FROM info';
    foreach ($conn->query($sql) as $row) {
        print $row['name'] . "\t";
    }
}
//call the function here
printResult($conn);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't call function `printResult` from anywhere.
Add to your code `printResult($conn);`